# Problem of the minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm new to the minimal polynomial. Here is a problem and its solution that I translated from Korean (so it might contain some errors):

> **Problem**
>
> Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $M_n(\mathbb C)$ be the vector space of all $n$-by-$n$ complex matrices. Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ satisfies $A^6 - A^3 + I = 0$.  Let $T:M_n(\mathbb C)\to M_n(\mathbb C)$ be a linear operator such that $T(B)=AB$. Show that $T$ is diagonalizable.
>
> **Solution**
>
> 1. From,$A^6 - A^3 + I = 0$, $(-A^3)^6=A^{18}=I$.
>      Thus the minimal polynomial $f(x)$ of $A$ divides $x^{18}-1$ and has distinct complex roots.
> 2. Meanwhile, for a nonnegative integer $k$, since $T^k(B)=A^kB (B \in V)$, $f(T)=0$.
> 3. Conversely, for a polynomial $g(x)$ s.t $g(T)=0$, $g(A)=0$ because $g(T)B=g(A)B=0$.
> 4. Thus the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $f(x)$.
> 5. Since $f(x)$ has distinct complex roots, $T$ is diagonalizable.

My Question:

a) I cannot understand 1). Why does  $x^{18}-1$ have distinct roots?
Also I understood that it has 18 distinct roots. Is that correct? (Or maybe two?)

b) Why do we need 2)~4)? Isn't it trivial that the minimal polynomial of a matrix and the corresponding transformation are same?

c) So the result says that $A$ was 18-by-18 matrix, right?

Thank you.

Comment: I do not understand the reasoning in (1), because if $A^6 - A^3 + I = 0$, then the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^6 - x^3 + 1$. Anyway, I think you can show that if $A$ is diagonalizable, then $T$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: I cannot understand either. I just translated the answer.. And that's the main reason I asked.

Comment: @Elvorfirilmathredia the point is that while it is not obvious that $x^6 - x^3 + 1 = 0$ has distinct roots, it **is** obvious (or at least more obvious) that $x^{18} = 1$ has distinct roots.

Comment: Also, it might not be obvious to everyone that $x^6-x^3+1$ divides $x^{18}-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

a) This is a fact about the complex numbers which is worth remembering: for any $n = 1,2,3,\dots$ the roots of the equation $x^n = 1$ are
$$
x = \exp(2 \pi ki/n), \quad k = 0,1,2,\dots,n-1
$$
(note: $\exp(i \theta) = e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin \theta$).
These roots are called the "$n$th roots of unity".  All $n$ of these roots are distinct.

b) Note that $T:M_n(\Bbb C) \to M_n(\Bbb C)$ is **not** the transformation that one would normally associate with the matrix $A$. The transformation that you're thinking of is $L_A: \Bbb C^n \to \Bbb C^n$ given by $x \mapsto Ax$.  Yes, both transformations involve multiplication by $A$, but the spaces involved are different.  $T$ is a map between two vector spaces of dimension $n^2$ whereas $L_A$ is a transformation between spaces of dimension $n$.

c) There is no reason to suppose that $A$ was $18 \times 18$.  In fact, we could make a $6 \times 6$ matrix with the required properties, for example, by using the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) associated with the given polynomial.

In fact, if we simply take $A = \omega I$ where $\omega$ is any solution to $\omega^6 - \omega^3 + 1 = 0$, then we have a satisfactory matrix which could work for any $n$.

---

To your comment below:

To see 2) in detail, what we've really said is that if $g$ is any polynomial such that $g(A) = 0$, then we have $g(T) = 0$.  This is true because for any $B$, 
$$
[g(T)](B) = g(A)B = 0B = 0
$$
*(However, since the polynomials satisfying $g(A) = 0$ are just the multiples of $f$, it was enough to consider $f(T))$*

In 3), we show that if $g$ is any polynomial such that $g(T) = 0$, then we have $g(A) = 0$.  In particular: if $g(T) = 0$, then we can say that for *every* $B$, we have
$$
[g(T)](B) = g(A)B = 0
$$
Now, it's up to you to show that because $g(A)B = 0$ for every $B \in M_n$, it must be the case that $g(A) = 0$.

Between parts 2) and 3), we have shown that a polynomial $g$ will satisfy $g(T) = 0$ if and only if it satisfies $g(A) = 0$.  Since we're looking at the same set of polynomials, of course the minimal polynomial (the lowest common divisor to this set) will be the same.

Comment: Thank you so much but I'm not sure why 2) and 3) implies 4). I think in order to conclude 4), we need 2) and the fact that f(x) is the lowest degree. It seems I don't really understand 3). And could you explain 3) more in detail? I think 3) only implies g(x) is a multiple of f(x). Sorry I added the question later.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: You are an angel.

Comment: @Cauchy glad to help (:. If the question has been answered to your satisfaction, be sure to accept the answer by clicking the $\checkmark$.